# For a research project I'm trying to estimate how many videos currently exist on Youtube

Tags: estimation, population, internet

Official stats on how many videos (rather than how many hours or what volume of data) seem quite hard to come by.

My current idea is something like this:

A youtube URL is like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1sjRD7NSec

where

```
 id = w1sjRD7NSec
```

Assuming that each character in the id can be upper (26) or lower (26) case letter or number (10)

the number of combinations should be

```
 = (26 + 26 +10 ) ^ 11

 = 62^11

 = 5.2 x 10 ^19
```

So if I write a script to try random urls of 100/1000/whatever videos, and Z% are successful, then will

```
 Z% x 5.2 x 10 ^19
```

give me the number of videos that exist (or at least are downloadable), albeit with a very low confidence?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @MarcClaesen looks like the last sentence should have had a ? at the end, so I added one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is yes. What you have is two columns, one is a long list of combinations and one with a 1 or a 0. 1 if there is a video at that combination and 0 if there is not a video. Were you to sum this second column, then this will give you the number of videos. For the whole population this works.

The only problem I see is in drawing a random sample as I have no idea how youtube generates its urls. You could of course send them an email and ask. I would just give it a shot with the script, try different ways to generate random urls take a large sample (n>1,000) and see whether the estimates are close enough.

Comment: +1 for send an email and ask. In this particular case, it seems like the best approach. I am fairly sure they will give you that information. As to drawing a random sample: the urls are *most likely* generated through hashing, which means any potential url is equally likely. This suggests trying out random urls is indeed a valid approach.